# Please post any example for threading in MFC?

Tags: mfc, multithreading

guys please post me an example for threading in MFC....it should show the progress and at the same time it should display the text,,if u anyone know some examples, please post me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Code Project is usually a good site to check for code examples.  This [example project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/mtguide_1.aspx) may help.

Answer (score 3):

On MSDN are these two examples about multithreading with MFC:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kk6acaf%28VS.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3wsyb55%28VS.80%29.aspx

On both pages are links to download the sample source code.